# Partially ordered sets

Tags: terminology, order-theory

I have a question on Posets.

Suppose we have $P = \{3, 6, 9, 18, 7, 14\} $ ordered by divisibility.
We want to partition $P$ to subsets so that each two elements in each subset are related directly or indirectly. For instance (3,6) are directly related because 6 is divisible by 3, and (6,9) are indirectly related because they are both divisible by 3. Another condition is that every subset must not have related element with another subset. 
The result of our example would be :

$P_1 = \{3, 6, 9, 18\} $ and 
$P_2 = \{7, 14\} $.

Is there a name for this kind of subsets? I need documentation about this kind of partitioning if it exists.

Comment: Just to be sure what you mean, if you added $2$ to $P$ would the sequence $7,14,2,18,6$ be valid to make an indirect relationship between $7$ and $6$?

Comment: My immediate thought was that you want to partition your poset into chains (see [Dilworth's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth's_theorem) on this question).  But actually you are asking for something else. Thanks to Mark Bennet for making me aware of that.

Comment: @MarkBennet Sorry for changing my answer again, yes 7 and 6 would be indirectly related. 14 is divisible by 7, and divisible by 2, and 6 is also divisible by 2, so 6 and 7 are indirectly related

Comment: So it looks as though you are splitting up the partial order into components, where the elements of component $A$ are all incomparable with any of the elements of component $B$. You also want that the components are connected in the sense that elements within the component are directly or indirectly related to each other.

Comment: @MarkBennet yes exactly, is there something similar in order theory? I found documentation on "directed sets" in which every two elements have common upper bounds,  but I think my case is different no?